# Google maps usage limits

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

My application has a store-locator functionality and we have implemented it in the following manner,
On the first page user gets a input text box where we have used google js places api, autocompleteservice. So we have included the following script tag

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&[OUR_KEY]'></script>
```

There is no map displayed on this page, however when the user clicks on search, the next page displays the map with user selected location and our stores around it. This page has the following script added

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&[OUR_KEY]}'></script>
```

Question:
1. Do we need to add the '[OUR_KEY]' value on both pages ?
2. If we have added it to both the pages, how will google charge ? Since the first page does not contain any map loads, will it count the hits for first page as well which has the autocompleteservice ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pricing and terms of use, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. Do we need to add the '[OUR_KEY]' value on both pages ?*

According to the Google Maps API FAQ

> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and the Maps Image APIs previously did not require an API console key. This is still supported for legacy applications to ensure backwards compatibility, but is no longer recommended for new applications.

Plus, some features arn't available whitout api key.

You can find more inforamtion about avaialble feature and commercial usage on the FAQ : https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

*2. If we have added it to both the pages, how will google charge ? Since the first page does not contain any map loads, will it count the hits for first page as well which has the autocompleteservice ?*

> your site or application generates 25 000 map loads or more each day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we’ll get in touch with you to talk about payment.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

For the JavaScript API, **only map loads are counted**

About The Places Library :
The Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API, is covered by the Google Maps JavaScript API limits.

So, the search for autocompletion will count for a request and the page load on the second page will also count in your quota.